# Convert varchar to time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried the links available here for similar questions before but it does not work. So I am posting my case here.

I have time in format:

```
09:47:11:895799
```

This is stored as `varchar(50)` in my Microsoft SQL Server database.

I am trying to convert it to time format as on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

```
hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]
```

Can you please help?

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: "it does not work" - in what way? An error message? The result is null or unexpected? Something else?

Comment: You need to change the last `:` to `.` before casting to `time`.

Comment: Please stop storing `time` in a `varchar` column. This is only one of many, many complications that will result from choosing the wrong data type...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The string is in the wrong format. It should be `09:47:11.895799`. You need to replace the final `:` with a `.`

```
SELECT CAST(STUFF('09:47:11:895799', 9,1,'.') AS TIME)
```

Comment: Yes that ':' was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user1949158 Remember to `accept` this answer if it meets your needs.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This did not work for SQL Server 2005. I had to use 
     `CONVERT(varchar(5), [column], 120)`

Answer (score 7):

You can also make your string as `hh:mi:ss:mmm` (24 hour format) and then `convert` as time. That means trimming out last 3 digits from your milli seconds without replacing last `':'` with `'.'`

Here is [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more details of formatting. Here is working example of [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7694)

```
DECLARE @s varchar(50) = '09:47:11:895799'
SELECT Convert(time, Left(@s,Len(@s)-3), 114)
```