# Converting varchar(6) in HHmmss format to sql time format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, time-format

How is it possible to convert something stored in `DB` as `varchar(6)` (e.g., 180000 which is actually in a format of `HHmmss`) to  time, I tried the following but wont work

```
select convert(time,'180000')
select cast('180000' as time)
```

Comment: don't store datetime as varchar.

Comment: I can't do anything on the DB its DBF imported, I take data to create RDLC reports

Comment: OK, did you searched here before posting ... there are many similar post present. example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293617/convert-varchar-to-time

Comment: Yes that didn't work

Comment: it works only when it is like select cast('18:00:00' as time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more approach

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(6)='180000';

SELECT CAST(STUFF(STUFF(@t,5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS time)
```

Thanks to @SebtHU, who pointed out, that this would not work with leading zeros in times such as `09:15:00` or `00:45:00`. You can use this instead:

```
SELECT CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000',@t),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS time);
```

Comment: NB this won't work with "no leading zeros" values like 91500 for 09:15:00, or 4500 for 00:45:00.  (msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules, for example, is full of these).  Need to add zeros on first e.g. with REPLICATE.

Comment: @SebTHU, thanks, you are right. I suggest to use something along `RIGHT(CONCAT('000000',@t),6)`

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
select cast((substring('180000',0,3)+':'+substring('180000',3,2)+':'+substring('180000',5,2)) as time)
```

Comment: The first substring should be `substring('180000',0,2)` not `substring('180000',0,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(format(180000, '00:00:00') as time), cast(format(131, '00:00:00') as time)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the DATEFROMPARTS function which allows you to receive a structure to form a schedule.

Syntax : `TIMEFROMPARTS ( hour, minute, seconds, fractions, precision )`

Problem solution:

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(6)='180000';
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS ( LEFT(@t,2), Substring(@t,3,2), RIGHT(@t,2), 0, 0 )
```

Result: `18:00:00`

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16