# convert varchar to month year format in sql server or javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, sql-server-2008

I have a ''varchar'' like '2020-08' in ''sql'' table. I need to convert it like 'Aug 2020' to show it in my web page.

select convert(varchar,'2020-08',107)

This does not seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert varchar to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293617/convert-varchar-to-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, why don't convert data directly in web page using `moment`? Something like:

```js
let data = '2020-08';

console.log(moment('2020-08').format("MMM YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```